# Change Pytest color output in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, python-3.6, pytest

I'm trying to change the color output of pytest in Terminal but haven't been able to do so. My current setup for changing color output in Terminal is found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command), but doesn't seem to work with pytest. The pytest output is currently colorized however, but I would like to change the colors. For instance, when a pytest test is run, and there's an error, the output is red, and I'd like it to be blue.

How can I change the colors used in the color output of pytest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to monkey-patch [`LOGLEVEL_COLOROPTS`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/08aed1a6bf90e2b8641aa464b41a41f1e400b59e/_pytest/logging.py#L23) but I doubt you could achieve much. It seems the colors are hard-coded. See for example [terminal.py](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/08aed1a6bf90e2b8641aa464b41a41f1e400b59e/_pytest/terminal.py#L326).

Comment: They do seem to be hardcoded. The only work around I've found so far is to go to Terminal>Preferences>ANSI Colors and change red to a different color. Unfortunately this doesn't limit the color change to pytest alone, but changes all red output for all programs run in Terminal.

Comment: @colossatr0n  This is the solution. In a black-background Terminal window, "ANSI red" is tough to read. Hence changing it, whether it appears from pytest or otherwise, solves the issue anticipating its use from other programs.